# Add a filter to markers that have been queried from a fusion table and then clustered with markerClusterer

Tags: javascript, sql, json, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I'm getting my markers and then clustering them like this:

```
    var query = "SELECT Latitude, Longitude, Icon, 'Nr.', Info, 'W/D/L' FROM " +
        '11jvxEY_amSEUy4IaWZE4652trcb3VLUu_x4XMUeD';
        var encodedQuery = encodeURIComponent(query);

        // Construct the URL
        var url = ['https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query'];
        url.push('?sql=' + encodedQuery);
        url.push('&key=AIzaSyAT76tcYefMoGlGrAgBhFFF22W8JhQyQBI');
        url.push('&callback=?');

        //example URL
        //https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT longitude_latitude FROM 1WukvEi1lbr-5Eo0Xn-Vqi5OKS7jhvt1aPmDdOD8I LIMIT 5&key=AIzaSyAT76tcYefMoGlGrAgBhFFF22W8JhQyQBI

        // Send the JSONP request using jQuery
        $.ajax({
          url: url.join(''),
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          success: function (data) {
            var rows = data['rows'];                

            var markers = [];
                for (var i in rows) {

                    //insert info window code
                    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

                    var lat = rows[i][0]
                    var lng = rows[i][2]
                    var image = rows[i][3]
                    var title = rows[i][3]
                    var content = rows[i][4]
                    var result = rows[i][5]
                    var coordinate = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng);


                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({'position': coordinate, 
                                                         'icon': image,
                                                         'title': 'Länderspiel #'+title,
                                                         'result': result
                                                         });

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', (function(marker, content) {
                      return function(){
                      infoWindow.setContent(content);
                      infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                      }
                    })(marker, content));

                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
                    infoWindow.close();
                    });

                    markers.push(marker);                       

                  }

            //   function filter() {
            //      var where = generateWhere();
            //      
            //      if (where) {
            //          if (!marker.getMap()) {
            //            marker.setMap;
            //          }
            //          marker.setOptions

                var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers);
            }
          });
```

I've begun to add a filter (commented out), trying to copy [this method](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/samples/in), but I'm not sure if that will work. I found another example, that seems to be doing exactly what I want, [here](http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-filtering.html), but I can't see, where they get the marker-properties they use to filter them from... I'd like to create a variable from the same query that assigns the markers different icons, getting info from the 'W/D/L' column (already included in the code), and then filter the markers by whether that information returns 'W', 'D', or 'L' (win, draw, or loss). I'm a noob, so can someone walk me through it?

Answer (score 0):

The conditions you may retrieve in any desired way, when the user should be able to define the conditions a checkbox should be appropriate, so create checkboxes with the desired values `W`,`D` and `L`.

Observe the click-event of the checkboxes and create the where-clause based on the values of the checked boxes. With jQuery it may look like this:

```
var where=[];
//ancestor is the common ancestor of all the checkboxes
$('input:checked',ancestor).each(function(){where.push(this.value)});
```

the result so far will be an array containing the values of the checked checkboxes, e.g. `['W','L']` .

This array now may be used to create the where-clause. The where-clause for the example-array should be :

```
where 'W/D/L' IN('W','L')
```

it may be created via:

```
" where 'W/D/L' IN('"+where.join("','")+"')"
```

append this where-clause to `query` and the results will be filtered.

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xd8Qp/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/xd8Qp/)

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I've been looking for! I'm just still struggling to implement it within my own code. Have tried just copying down your entire demo and filling in the gaps, but then the map didn't render... I'll have more time to work on it tomorrow, but some additional pointers on how to implement the filter AND keep my additional fusiontableLayer in there would be great! I also have a follow-up question on how to add a second filter, which would be a dropdown based on the value 'Gegner', that should filter both the markers and the layers, but one problem at a time...

Comment: have you replaced the google-key in the fiddle with your own key(there is a related comment in the code)? The key used in the demo is only valid for my own jsfiddle-playground.

Answer (score 0):

This is an addition to the answer provided by @DrMolle.

I tried to copy @DrMolle's demo, but the map initially did not render the markers as well.

It worked after including the necessary script sources which were missing:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```